# On MacOS with Qt5.3.1 QToolBar is black when attached

Tags: macos, qt5

I have a QMainWindow Application that uses several QToolBars. My program works on Linux, Windows and MacOS, however on MacOs the QToolbar behaves a little bit funky. When attached to the MainWindow it is just black as shown here [image: black tool bar]

When I detach it it is grey as you would expect it to be [image: grey toolbar]

Also when I maximize to program the toolbar creates artifacts like this [image]

Do I need any MacOS specific things for the QToolBar?

Comment: So if I set setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac( false ); it won't be black anymore. However the double layer on maximize still exists.

Comment: Also similar behaviour in Qt 5.4.0 (via PyQt5)

Answer (score 0):

I'm hitting this bug too. I think it is linked to using non-alien widgets inside the toolbar or app wide.

Are you using `setAttribute(Qt::AA_NativeWindows);`? If so, try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have a QGLWidget-based UI element in your application? If so, apparently this is a known issue.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41679

I am experiencing the "double-vision" aspect of this on a Qt 5.7.0-based app.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It helps to post a full answer here, instead of a link. If the link stops working, the answer is lost.